# Notation for sets of unordered pairs

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

Let $A$ be a finite set of unordered pairs, e.g., $$A = \{\{1, 2\}, \{1, 3\}, \{2, 3\}\} \enspace .$$ Which of the following is proper notation for "the element $\{1, 2\}$ belongs to $A$"?

- $\{1, 2\} \in A$
- $\{1, 2\} \subsetneq A$
- $\{\{1, 2\}\} \subsetneq A$

The second option makes no sense at all, but would the first and the third be equally appropriate?

Comment: **Hint:** What if $A=\{\{1,2\}, \{2,1\}\}$? Would $\{1,2\}\in A$ hold? What about $\{\{1,2\}\}\subsetneq A$?

Comment: The second makes sense but is simply wrong.  The third is true but not appropriate as it means "the set containing the unordered pair 1,2 is a subset of A" which is not what was being asked.  What was asked was "the unordered pair 1,2 is an element of A" and that is what the first literally saying.  The third and the first are equivalent but they state different things.

Comment: The first says that the element $\{1,2\}$ belongs to the set $A$. The third says that the element $\{1,2\}$ belongs to the set $A$ **and is not the only member of** $A$. Even if you change $\subsetneq$ to $\subseteq$, making the first and third equivalent, the third is an unnecessarily confusing and roundabout way to say what you want.

Comment: @Workaholic If $A = \{\{1, 2\}\}, \{2, 1\}\} = \{\{1, 2\}\}$, so $\{1, 2\} \in A$ would hold, but $\{\{1, 2\}\} \subsetneq A$ wouldn't, right?

Comment: @Cromack Exactly! Note however that $\{\{1,2\}\}\subseteq A$ is a correct alternative notation for “$\{1,2\}$ belongs to $A$”.

Comment: @Workaholic Great! Thank you all for the help :)

Comment: @Cromack You're welcome! ;-)

Comment: Good point.  They *aren't* equivalent after all.  But even if they were, the question is "what is the proper notation for a being a member of A".  The proper notation is $a \in A$ and not $\{a\} \subseteq A$.  They are equivalent statements but they express different (albeit equivalent) concepts.  Like "I am 30 years old" is different than "I was born 30 years ago".

Answer (score 0):

Your first answer is correct. If an element (a single element or a set of elements) belongs to a set, it is represented using the element of operator; therefore: $$\{1, 2\} \in A$$ You would use the element of operator. Also, option 3 is correct because that element is a set itself, and it is a subset of the finite set $A$. So, also $$\{\{1, 2\}\} \subsetneq A$$ The first and third are therefore equally appropriate.